# Different version of numpy installed and the version used in jupyter notebook

Tags: numpy, pip

As stated, the version shown in my terminal is of 1.24.2 but in my jupyter notebook reflects 1.19.5 instead.

Here is what is reflected on my terminal (packages in environment at `/opt/anaconda3`):

```
#Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
numpy                     1.24.2                   pypi_0    pypi
numpydoc                  1.4.0            py39hecd8cb5_0
```

I recalled trying to update the numpy version using `pip install numpy --upgrade` which it successfully downloaded but do face an error when installing but nonetheless it still installed the 1.24.2 version.

Comment: Did you try running `%pip install numpy --upgrade` in a cell inside the notebook, then restart kernel and now check the version?  See use of 'Use of the %pip install magic' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75816975/8508004) for more about the magic install command that insures the installation occurs in the environment that the kernel is running.

Comment: That worked. Thank you =) I suppose its due to how i have 2 different environment which I have updated 1 of the environment but not the other.